# How to drop multilevel and rename in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe with multiple indeces

```
        balance                                 account_age   token_trading_activity
        last        mean        first           last          mean
address                 
A       8401.072266 7108.331543 4.554461e+03    22            2.654430e+06
B       12.392011   1.829049    0.000000e+00    22            5.732227e+03
C       0.171628    0.072315    1.000000e-04    19            4.641053e+02
D       0.169349    0.079693    1.000000e-18    17            4.149412e+02
E       0.289523    0.143305    1.000000e-18    17            2.705882e+0
```

I want to drop multiple indices and rename my dataframe such that it look like the following

```
address balance_last balance_mean initial       account_age   token_trading_mean                
A       8401.072266  7108.331543  4.554461e+03  22            2.654430e+06
B       12.392011    1.829049     0.000000e+00  22            5.732227e+03
C       0.171628     0.072315     1.000000e-04  19            4.641053e+02
D       0.169349     0.079693     1.000000e-18  17            4.149412e+02
E       0.289523     0.143305     1.000000e-18  17            2.705882e+0
```

Comment: posted an answer, is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# iterate over the multi-level columns names
# using list comprehension, concatenate them

df.columns=[col[0]+" "+col[1] for col in df.columns]
```